# Azure DevOps Release pipeline does not support https

Tags: azure, https, azure-devops, pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to deploy RestAPI with https port for .net core 3.1 project. 
I can run it manually by Powershell. 
But when I try to run Powershell in Azure DevOps Release Pipeline. 
Below is setup steps:

1. Stop Current RestAPI process + Delete all current file.
2. Extract new release to target deploy folder
3. Start Rest API process with port defined:

```
Start-Process -FilePath $env:WebsiteLocation\$env:ProcessName --urls="$env:PortNumber" -WorkingDirectory $env:WebsiteLocation
```

- If PortNumber is http://... it work. new process start in deploy agent
- If PortNumber is https://... it didn't work. no any process is started

Could you please help share with the reason why i got this issue. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, are you running that using a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops)? And do you mean it works well when you use local Powershell to run the same command with https url? If so,  could you please share some steps(details about how to create a minimal sample) for us to reproduce same issue?

Comment: Hello Lance, thank you for your reply. Yes. i use my local PC as a deployment agent. Just create the simple .net core rest API project. The expect is, I able to deploy the rest API with Https port. But I can't.

Comment: Hi , if it works with https port in local powershell but not powershell task, I suggest you should check the log of Powershell Task to see if there's any useful info there. It would be better if you can share the details about your pipeline(jobs,tasks) , also the logs of your PS task in pipeline, and the result when you use local powershell to start with https port.